# How to add an Event Listener to a dynamically added field using Symfony Forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I am using event listeners to dynamically modify a form. I want to add another event listener to a field that was added dynamically. Im not sure how to accomplish this.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('first_field','choice',array(
        'choices'=>array('1'=>'First Choice','2'=>'Second Choice')
    ));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'preSetData'));
    $builder->get('first_field')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, array($this, 'postSubmit'));
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $form->add('second_field','choice',array(
        'choices'=>array('1'=>'First Choice','2'=>'Second Choice')
    ));
    //Some how add an event listener to this field

}

public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
    $form->add('second_field','choice',array(
        'choices'=>array('1'=>'First Choice','2'=>'Second Choice')
    ));
    //Some how add an event listener to this field
}
```

I have trie just using the `$builder` in the `buildForm` function to add the event listener to the `second_field` but because the field doesnt exist when the form is initially generated it throws an error.

If i try and add the new event listener inside the first event listener by doing:

```
$form->get('second_field')->addEventListener(...)
```

Then i get the error:

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::addEventListener()
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to add a third field based on the second field?

Comment: Yes, and the second field is based on the first. Similar to Select Country -> then based on country selected the field states is added and available States are populated based on country. Then once a state is selected a City field would be added and available cities would be populated into it.

Comment: You might want to look at the [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle)

Comment: Not a bad idea, I would however like to avoid adding a new vendor if possible though. Its just 1 more dependency to rely on. However if i cant get this working natively i may give it a try.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher I am not sure why you recommend the CraueFormFlowBundle. It's for making multi-step forms.  This question is about adding fields dynamically to a form based on underlying data.

Comment: @BraydenWilliams The bundle looks like it should be able to accomplish what i want. Its just a lot of fluff that i dont need as well.

Comment: @Chausser, Did you able to call POST_SUBMIT event listener to dynamically added field? I have similar issue and I am struggling a bit!

Answer (score 17):

If, is it actually.

FormInterface does't have the addEventListener method, but FormBuilderIntreface have it. If you want to add any listener, you should to create form field by form builder.

For example:

```
   // create builder for field
   $builder = $form->getConfig()->getFormFactory()->createNamedBuilder($name, $type, null, array(
       /** any options **/
       'auto_initialize'=>false // it's important!!!
   ));
   // now you can add listener
   $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, $yourCallbackHere)

   // and only now you can add field to form  
   $form->add($builder->getForm());
```

Comment: OMG, you saved my day, my started work and my motivation ! Many thanks.. !

Answer (score 3):

I have just spent half of my working day struggling on this. I'm using symfony 3.2.x and the best thing that helped me is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415352/symfony2-double-nested-dynamic-form-fields).

I had a triple dependece (country,state,region,zipcode) i've solved all inside the same FormType:

```
    /** @var  EntityManager $em */
private $em;

/**
 * GaraFormType constructor.
 *
 * @param EntityManager $em
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em        = $em;
}


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('country', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'       => 'Country',
            ...more attrs
        ));

    $this->stateAjaxFieldFormListener($builder);
    $this->cityAjaxFieldFormListener($builder);
    $this->zipCodeAjaxFieldFormListener($builder);
}
```

Each of those functions handles one of the dynamic fields, and they are all the same as follows:

```
private function stateAjaxFieldFormListener(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
{
    $localizationFormModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
        $stateInCountry = $this->em->getRepository("State")->findBy(array("country" => $country));

        if ($form->has('state') && ! $form->isSubmitted()) {
            $form->remove('state');
        }
        $form
            ->add('state', EntityType::class, array(
                'choices'     => $stateInCountry,
                'class'       => 'State',
            ));
    };
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($localizationFormModifier) {
        /** @var ClienteTemp $data */
        $data    = $event->getData();
        $country = null !== $data ? $data->getCountry() : null;

        $localizationFormModifier($event->getForm(), $country);
    });
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($localizationFormModifier) {
        $data      = $event->getData();
        $countryId = array_key_exists('country', $data) ? $data['country'] : null;
        $country   = $this->em->getRepository("Country")->find($countryId);
        $localizationFormModifier($event->getForm(), $country);
    });
}
```

Just change entity references for the other two functions: cityAjaxFieldFormListener and zipCodeAjaxFieldFormListener

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to add the event listener to `first_field` or `second_field` themselves.  You can keep the event listener on the parent form and check both the submitted and the set data for whether or not it includes data for `first_field`.  If it does, add the `second_field`.   In the same listener, check if data has been set or submitted to `second_field`.  If it has, add the third field.

There is a similar concept outlined in the documentation here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Comment: I have gone over that guide 100 times, The problem i have is still you have to attach to the `post_submit` listener. And the only way to do that according to that guide is to attach it to the field directly. There in lies the problem, since i cant attach the `post_submit` listener to a field that has been dynamically added by a different listener.

Comment: This works fine for the `pre_set_data` event because that is attached to the parent form and i can check the nesting all the way down. The issue just comes with the `post_submit` event

Comment: Why do you have to do the check in post_submit?  I have cascading  country/state/city fields in one of my apps and I check in pre_submit.

Comment: I'll try it without and let you know